# How to make custom display resolution

Tags: display-resolution

If I try to set monitor to `1920x1080` but I lose the the some of the screen. Under windows my monitor is resized to `1804x1014` to fit the whole screen.

How do I tell Ubuntu to use `1804x1014` resolution?

thanks

Comment: What GPU Nvidia, AMD or intel

Comment: what is the output of  `gtf 1804 1014 59.9`

Comment: 1808x1014 @ 59.90 Hz (GTF) hsync: 62.90 kHz; pclk: 151.95 MHz
  Modeline "1808x1014_59.90"  151.95  1808 1920 2112 2416  1014 1015 1018 1050  -HSync +Vsync

Comment: Nvidia video card and AMD cpu

Comment: based on the output of gtf, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Use gtf to create a mode line

```
gtf 1804 1014 59.9
```

Add new mode using xrandr

```
 xrandr --newmode "1804x1014_59.90"  151.95  1808 1920 2112 2416  1014 1015 1018 1050  -HSync +Vsync
```

Add this newly added mode

```
 xrandr --addmode VGA 1804x1014_59.90
```

Choose the new mode

```
xrandr --output VGA --mode 1804x1014_59.90
```

TO MAKE THE CHANGES PERSISTENT

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

MAKE SURE YOU ADD YOUR NEW RESOLUTION TO THE MODES LINE

```
Modes "..." "1804x1014" "...."
```

Comment: My output is listed up above. Can I cut and paste directly from this post?

Comment: yes you can do so...

Comment: Unfortuanately I'm not as technical as most people on Linux. I just want to change the resolution, but its not working. Which sucks because I have a decent monitor and a decent video card. sigh

Comment: Got to the xrandr --addmode VGA 1804x1014_59.90 stage and it says "xrandr: cannot find output "VGA"

Comment: I really need help with this. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to the native resolution of my monitor.